# How to wrap cordova around an existing nuxt.js project?

Tags: cordova, vue.js, nuxt.js

I got an existing nuxt.js project. Now I want to deploy my code for Android and IOS, therefore I want to use Cordova.

I did a lot of research but could not find a solution. I found a plugin https://github.com/m0dch3n/vue-cli-plugin-cordova that seemed to get the job done. I installed it and ran "npm run cordova-serve-android" but it gave me this error:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./src/main.js in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.28:8080/sockjs-node 
(webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 
./src/main.js, multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 
(webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.28:8080/sockjs-node ./src/main.js
```

Unfortunately, there is not a single issue with Nuxt on the github plugin page, so I assume this plugin is not for Nuxt. Is there a tutorial or plugin compatible with Nuxt?

Comment: Isn't running `yarn nuxt generate` and moving the generated files to your cordova `www` dir enoguh? i don't think it matters if you use nuxtJs or (in my case) jquery.mobile as they are static files

Answer (score 2):

I made an example repo of this trying to find a bug, you can use it as an example. Basically you add these few things to your nuxt config

```
mode: 'spa',
generate: {
    dir: 'www',
},
build: {
   publicPath: '/android_asset/www/front-end',
},
scripts: [
  {
    src: '/cordova.js',
    type: 'text/javascript',
  },
],
```

This is for android of course, can adjust the public path for ios. Then all you need to do is

```
nuxt generate
```

Setup a script to move the folder from `www/android_asset/www/front-end` to `www/front-end`

```
cordova add platform android@latest --save
cordova run android
```

This is without using any extra plugins, just adding cordova to an existing nuxt repo. It is not complete however, just an example, still needs index.js, and to wait for things like device ready from the cordova docs.

https://github.com/amritk/min-repro-nuxt-cordova